# Judas from tribe of Dan

Tags: revelation

In Revelation 7, None were sealed from the tribe of Dan.  In John 13:18 Jesus says “I know those I have chosen.”  John 13:21.  “I tell you the truth, one of you is going to betray me.”
Could Judas have been from the tribe of Dan, and so was proscribed from entering the kingdom?

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Do you mean the Judas that betrayed Jesus.  [There are several people called "Judas" in the NT.]

Comment: The more interesting question here appears to be that John does not even recognize that the tribe of Dan even existed - 12 tribe list that differs from all others in the OT.

Comment: I believe Genesis 49 is the reason Dan is not mentioned in Revelation 7.

Comment: How do you know that Judas "*was proscribed from entering the kingdom*"?

Comment: What people fail to notice is that the NAME of Ephraim is also missing. Both tribes are associated with the two calves of Jeroboam. They are replaced by Levi and Joseph. Two "unfaithful" names have been replaced by two "faithful" names.  It is a mistake to focus on Dan alone.

Answer (score 1):

Judges 18:

> 1 In those days Israel had no king.
> And in those days the tribe of the **Danites** was seeking a place of their own where they might settle, because they had not yet come into an inheritance among the tribes of Israel.
>
> So they entered the hill country of Ephraim and came to the house of Micah, where they spent the night.

The Danites took Micah's idol.

> 28b The Danites rebuilt the city and settled there. 29They named it Dan after their ancestor Dan, who was born to Israel—though the city used to be called Laish. 30There the **Danites set up for themselves the idol**, and Jonathan son of Gershom, the son of Moses, and his sons were priests for the tribe of Dan until the time of the captivity of the land. 31They continued to use the **idol** Micah had made, all the time the house of God was in Shiloh.

Many years later, King Jeroboam reinforced this practice in 1 Kings 12:

> 28 After seeking advice, the king made two golden calves. He said to the people, “It is too much for you to go up to Jerusalem. Here are your gods, Israel, who brought you up out of Egypt.” 29One he set up in Bethel, and the other in **Dan**. 30And this thing became a sin; the people came to worship the one at Bethel and went as far as Dan to worship the other.

https://biblehub.com/commentaries/revelation/7-4.htm

Benson explains why the tribe of Dan is missing from Revelation 7:

> Dan is entirely omitted, being the first tribe that fell into idolatry after the settlement of Israel in Canaan; and also being early reduced to a single family, which family itself seems to have been cut off in war **before** the time of Ezra. For in the Chronicles, where the posterity of the patriarchs is recited, Dan is wholly omitted.

Meyer concurs:

> The simplest reason for not naming Dan lies rather in the fact that it had died out **long** already before the time of John.

If this is true, then
Judas Iscariot could not have been from the tribe of Dan.

Comment: How do you understand James 1:1?

Comment: Excellent point. I don't know at the moment. I will have to research it. BTW, I have not arrived at any conclusion in my answer above. I'd be interested in how you answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

Some people say it is because Dan fell into idolatry, or they were the first tribe to fall into idolatry. Neither one of those arguments are compelling since we know all tribes brought their idols with them into the land, as Joshua chides them for doing so.

Some say that Dan died out long before, but where does that leave God and His promises, that He would allow a tribe to die out?

Some say that Dan was subsumed under Judah or another tribe, but the so called lost tribes are listed in the New Testament, and also King Josiah restored worship even into Samaria.

A good reason for believing Judas was from the tribe of Dan, is that Dan isn’t listed in Revelation, but it isn’t compelling by itself. But possibly, if you look at Deuteronomy 27, you’ll notice there are twelve tribes and twelve curses. Line up the tribes listed, and Dan would be the one receiving the curse of, “Cursed be anyone who takes a bribe to shed innocent blood.” Some people believe because of this, Dan is the “Judas” tribe, and therefore left out.

Something else to keep in mind here though is that Dan is listed in Ezekiel’s vision in Ezekiel 48.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

None is compelling, since Dan is mentioned on the gate of New Jerusalem, even though Dan is not mentioned in the sealed people (Rev.).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is evidence that the tribe of Dan migrated around the black sea, other places as well, and many ended up in Greece. Anti-Christ will have roots in the tribe of Dan, hence Dan did not die out.

Comment: Welcome to the site, F.Dugan. Just to point out that this Q has got nothing to do with geography but requires examining 2 N.T. texts, the OP seeking any connection between what was said around 33A.D., and what the other said around 95A.D. The Q is not asking about 'anti-christ'. Whatever answer is posted, this site requires research evidence to back it up, not just stating one's opinion. Can you adjust your answer accordingly?